# Filter files whose names contain a keyword in CMD

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe

In working on a script that computes, and outputs to a file, the total cyclomatic complexities of a project under test, I am trying to filter out files whose names (including path) contains "test". (Such files only exist for testing purposes, and are therefore exempt from computation.)

So far, I have the following code:

```
rem write temporary file, to append command line output to
SETLOCAL 
SET tmpfile=tmp_ComplexityAnalysis.txt
echo. 2>%tmpfile%
rem perform cyclomatic complexity analysis on all the files, iff those files are not test files and have some functions in them
echo %tmpfile%
for /R apiserver_sdk %%G in (*.go) DO (
    rem filter out "test" files
    gocyclo %%G >> %tmpfile%
)
```

I don't know how to exclude "test" or where.

**UPDATE**: Changing the body of the for loop to :

```
DIR /A %%G| findstr test
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 (
    rem filter out "test" files
    gocyclo %%G >> %tmpfile%
)
```

doesn't work because, somehow, `%ERRORLEVEL%` is always zero.

Comment: I can confirm your result, that `%ErrorLevel%` is always zero. I get the same result with `find`. The `grep.exe` port of the Unix utility gives the correct return status, but I'm looking for a work-round using standard commands. I need to go out now: if no-one has come with an answer by the time I get back, I'll look into it further. By the way, why use `DIR /A %%G|...`, rather than `echo %%G|...`?

Comment: Yup. That would be me! My day job is software development

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the questioner has found, `%ErrorLevel%` is not being set. I don't know whether delayed expansion and `!ErrorLevel!` would work, but what I found was that `findstr` is setting its return value, so either of the following scripts works:-

```
for /R apiserver_sdk %%G in (*.go) DO (
    rem filter out "test" files
    echo %%G | findstr /i test
    if errorlevel 1 ( 
        gocyclo %%G >> %tmpfile%
    )
)
```

or:-

```
for /R apiserver_sdk %%G in (*.go) DO (
    rem filter out "test" files
    echo %%G | findstr /i test || (
        gocyclo %%G >> %tmpfile%
    )
)
```

If the `gocyclo` command is the only one needed, the command group surrounding it could be removed.

Comment: That was simple!

Answer (score 0):

```
DIR /B | FOR /F %x IN ('FIND "test"') DO (
    ECHO Execute something using "%x"
)
```

Backwards, to exclude files which contains `"test"` substring in a name - add `/V` key to the `FIND` command.

[image: screenshot]

> this needs to happen for all the `.go` files in the directory that don't have `"test"` in their pathnames

```
DIR /B *.go | FOR /F %x IN ('FIND /V "test"') DO(
    ECHO Execute something using "%x"
)
```

Comment: It didn't work. I get this at runtime: 

```C:\Users\mwarren\Desktop>echo tmp_ComplexityAnalysis.txt
tmp_ComplexityAnalysis.txt
IN was unexpected at this time.

C:\Users\mwarren\Desktop>       DIR /B | FOR /F x IN ('FIND /V "test"') DO (```

Prepending `%` to the variables doesn't make it work, either.

Also, where do you use `%%G` in your solution?

Comment: *It didn't work.* Method works - screenshot added. Apply it in your code.  *where do you use %%G in your solution?* I use `%x` - replace if need.

Comment: I simply inserted your for loop into mine. Keep in mind that this needs to happen *for all the .go files in the directory* that don't have "test" in their pathnames

Comment: This is a clumsy way of doing `for %f in (*test*) do ( ... )`, which, as the questioner says, is the _opposite_ of what he wants.